# Particles System Generating random particles all over the scene

Tags: particles

I am trying to generate these contrails from the jet. But for some reason the contrails are also emitting from the world origin even though there is no emitter at the origin. Emitter is linked to the jet's wings which is constrained to a path.
Any ideas on fixing this issue? thanks.

[image][image]

Comment: how shall we help you when we have no idea what you did and if you don't show us any settings you made? please provide a blend file so that we can help you. thx.

Comment: You will have to show us your settings, which can be quite extensive.. perhaps your best tactic will be to create the simplest example you can that fails in this way, illustrate it, and share it on https://blend-exchange.com/ . At the moment, this question is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'. We do want to help, but need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I found that increasing the cache steps fixes this issue. But am not sure if this fix is permanent or temporary. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).